# How to shrink the spacing between Cell Header and Cell Text in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is it possible to shrink the spacing between a cell header and cell text? Looking at the example below I'd like the header to be closer to the top of the cell that contains the other text.

Sorry, I don't have high enough reputation to embed images.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6afdd58c2f.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: in your controller and return your desired height.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 50.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a standard cell style and textLabel.  You could change the frame.origin of the label, or create a custom cell from a nib with the exact layout you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use method `heightForHeaderInSection` for defining space between header & cell text.
You can also change it depending on different sections for eg. at some sections you  may need to show more distance & under some, you don't want to show gap. 
For such case you can use CGFLOAT_MIN which is 0.000001f.
Giving you an example, how you can use different section with different header heights

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0 || section == 2)
    {
        return 55.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return CGFLOAT_MIN;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.